# Correct proof for Formula for Probability density function of a function of a random variable?

Tags: proof-verification, probability-distributions

Assume we have a random variable $X$ that has a probability density function $f_X(x)$. Now let $y:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be a real valued function, so that $y(X)$ is another random variable. **Problem**: find the probability density function $f_{y(X)}(x)$.

**Solution.**  Note that $X\in I\implies y(X)\in y(I)$ for any interval $I$. Therefore:

$$\forall I:P(X\in I)=P(y(X)\in y(I))$$

Hence,
$$\forall I:\int_If_X(s)ds=\int_{y(I)}f_{y(X)}(s)ds$$

We now rewrite the interval as $(x,x+dx)$ for some $x,dx\in\mathbb R$
$$\forall x\forall dx:\int_x^{x+dx} f_X(s)ds=\int_{y(x)}^{y(x+dx)}f_{y(X)}(s)ds$$

If we define $F(x)$ as the antiderivative of $f_{y(X)}(x)$ then the latter integral becomes $F(y(x+dx))-F(y(x))$, which is equal to $G(x+dx)-G(x)$ if we define $G(x)=F(y(x))$. Then $G'(x)=y'(x)*f_{y(X)}(y(x))$. So if we convert back to integral form we get $\int_x^{x+dx}G'(s)ds=\int_x^{x+dx}y'(s)f_{y(X)}(y(s))ds$.
Therefore:

$$\forall x\forall dx:\int_x^{x+dx} f_X(s)ds=\int_x^{x+dx}y'(s)f_{y(X)}(y(s))ds$$

Since this is true for all $dx$, it is in particular also true for the limit of $dx$ to $0$. Therefore, by the fundamental theorem of calculus,

$$f_X(s)=y'(s)f_{y(X)}(y(s))$$

**Is this solution correct, and is the proof rigorous?**

Comment: Already your first statement is wrong… Let $y=x^2$ and $X \sim \mathcal{U}[-1,1]$ Then $$P(X \in [0,1]) = \frac{1}{2} \not= 1 = P(y(X) \in y([0,1]) = P(X^2 \in [0,1])$$. All you have from $$X\in I\implies y(X)\in y(I)$$ is $$\forall I:P(X\in I) \le P(y(X)\in y(I))$$

Comment: @Gono, oops... If we additionally assume that $y(x)$ is monotonic, would that make the proof correct? Is there a way to solve this problem for an arbitrary function $y(x)$?

Comment: monotonic is not enough, monotony need to be strict to fix that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about whether or not $f_X(s)=y'(s)f_{y(X)}(y(s))$ always satisfies all the properties of a density function. Is it always positive? Being more careful about the direction that $dx$ approaches zero should solve this problem.

The only other problem might sound a bit nitpicky, but you might want to change the problem's statement to make it clear that $y(x)$ is differentiable.